# BCD Timer in VHDL

Tags: timer, vhdl, counter, bcd

Just started out in VHDL not long ago,out of curiosity.

So I was trying to write BCD timer on spartan 3 board and

Somehow I couldn't find out why it keeps showing 'unexpected with' error.

So if I want to have such function as shown in the link of picture,
how can I modify the code?any help would be grateful.

[image: my initial sketch_picture link to imgur]
(clickable)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity w3 is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
           stp : in  STD_LOGIC;
           an : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           c : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
end w3;

architecture timer of w3 is
signal div1 : integer range 0 to 499999 :=0; -- 100Hz
signal ck100hz : std_logic; -- 100Hz output
signal div2 : integer range 0 to 249999 :=0; -- 200Hz
signal ck200hz : std_logic; -- 200Hz output
signal div3 : integer range 0 to 124999 :=0; -- 400Hz
signal ck400hz : std_logic; -- 400Hz output
signal index : integer range 0 to 9 :=0;
signal scan : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal S : std_logic;
signal disp : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

begin
process begin
wait until rising_edge(clk);
if div1 < 499999 then
    ck100hz <= '0';
    div1 <= div1+1;
else 
    ck100hz <= '1';
    div1 <= 0;
end if;
if div2 < 249999 then
    ck200hz <= '0';
    div2 <= div2+1;
else
    ck200hz <= '1';
    div2 <= 0;
end if;
if div3 < 124999 then
    ck400hz <= '0';
    div3 <= div3+1;
else
    ck400hz <= '1';
    div3 <= 0;
end if;
end process;

process begin
wait until rising_edge(clk);
if rst = '1' then 
    index <= 0; 
end if;
if stp = '1' then 
    index <= index; 
end if;

if ck100hz = '1' then
    if index < 3 then index <= index+1;
        else index <= 0;
        if index < 4 and index > 7 then index <= index+1;
            else index <= 0;
            if index < 8 and index > 11 then index <= index+1;
                else index <= 0;
                if index < 12 and index > 15 then index <= index+1;
                    else index <= 0;
   end if;
      end if;
          end if;
             end if;
end if;
end process;

process begin
wait until rising_edge(clk);
if ck400hz = '1' then
    With scan select -- error unexpected With
        an <= an(0) when "00",
              an(1) when "01",
              an(2) when "10",
              an(3) when others;
end if;
end process;

process begin
wait until rising_edge(clk);
if ck200hz = '1' then
    With S select   -- error unexpected With
    disp <= index integer range 0 to 3 when "00",
            index integer range 4 to 7 when "01",
            index integer range 8 to 11 when "10",
            index integer range 12 to 15 when others;
end if;
end process;




with index select
    C <= "1000000" when 0, 
          "1111001" when 1, 
          "0100100" when 2, 
          "0110000" when 3, 
          "0011001" when 4, 
          "0010010" when 5, 
          "0000010" when 6,
          "1111000" when 7,       
          "0000000" when 8,
          "0011000" when 9;

end timer;
```

Comment: `with`is not supported in sequential code (e.g. processes). No need for so many `end if`, Use `elsif` branches to minimize the depths of statements. You should not write low-active code. There is no driver for `scan` ans `S`.

Comment: @Paebbels I thought this was a high-active code?What do you mean by no driver for `scan` and `S`?
I'm not quite familiar with `elsif` so I use that many `end if`...
Ok,If `with...select` cannot be used in `process` then what can I use to make the function to work?
Thanks for helping.
edit: If you don't mind,please make an example.

Comment: ISE doesn't support -2008 syntax changes (sequential selected signal assignment). ISE XST does not support concurrent selected signal assignment either. A sequential selected signal assignment has an equivalent case statement. This isn't a code writing service, perhaps you ask a specific question? `an` isn't right, only one element should be true at a time (assign the whole thing). `disp` isn't used, you don't appear to have a BCD counter, `index` is only assigned 0 or it's current value. `div1`, `div2` and `div3` are only evaluated for increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For low-active:**
You should assign `0111111` to `C` in case of `index = 0`. You have to enable almost all segments.  Now your internal calculation would be high-active. The display itself is low-active, because of the PCB layout, thus you should invert the whole `C` vector before assigning it to a `Cathode_n` port: `Cathode_n <= not C;` Note, I used `_n` to designate the low-active behavior of this port.

Old code:

```
with index select
  C <= "1000000" when 0, 
       "1111001" when 1,
       -- ...
       "0011000" when 9;
```

This should be the goal when writing purely high-active code:

```
with index select
  C <= "0111111" when 0, 
       "0000110" when 1,
       -- ...
       "1100111" when 9;

  Cathode_n <= not C;
```

High-active means: If a bit is high (`1`) then a thing is active. In your case an LED of a 7-segment display is activated. Based on the PCB design, you have to drive low (`0`) to activate a light. This is low-active, because a low value activates something.

The select statement needs to assign the position to `1` that should be enlightened, not the positions to turn off. More over low-active signals should be marked in to code to denote there different behavior. Only a top-level component should translate high-active signals to low-active signals and vice versa. This ensures, the inner parts of your design are purely high-active.

---

**For no driver:**
There is no assignment to `S` and `scan`. Both signals are `'U'` or `"UUUU"`, respectively.

Edit:
Each signal assignment creates a driver on a signal. Currently, your code never assigns any value to `S` nor `scan`. Thus the initial values of `S` and `scan` become the driving value of the signals. You should run a simulation und see a lot of `U`s in your waveform.

Synthesis tools might report: Signal `S` is read, but never assigned.

---

**For using `elsif`:**

I reformatted you horrible if-then-else construct:

```
if ck100hz = '1' then
  if index < 3 then
    index <= index+1;
  else
    index <= 0;
    if index < 4 and index > 7 then
      index <= index+1;
    else
      index <= 0;
      if index < 8 and index > 11 then
        index <= index+1;
      else
        index <= 0;
        if index < 12 and index > 15 then
          index <= index+1;
        else
          index <= 0;
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end if;
```

Now we see, you code can not use *elsif*, because you have assignments in the *else* branch before the next *if* statement. On the otherhand, the `index <= 0;` assignment is redundant and can be removed:

```
if ck100hz = '1' then
  if index < 3 then
    index <= index+1;
  else
    if index < 4 and index > 7 then
      index <= index+1;
    else
      if index < 8 and index > 11 then
        index <= index+1;
      else
        if index < 12 and index > 15 then
          index <= index+1;
        else
          index <= 0;
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end if;
```

Now we can transform it to use *elsif* branches:

```
if ck100hz = '1' then
  if index < 3 then
    index <= index + 1;
  elsif index < 4 and index > 7 then
    index <= index + 1;
  elsif index < 8 and index > 11 then
    index <= index + 1;
  elsif index < 12 and index > 15 then
    index <= index+1;
  else
    index <= 0;
  end if;
end if;
```

Much more readable, right?

Next, lets check your expressions in that statement:

```
elsif index < 4 and index > 7 then
```

`index` cannot be less than 4 and greater than 7 at the same time. So lets play synthesis and optimized away unreachable branches:

```
if ck100hz = '1' then
  if index < 3 then
    index <= index + 1;
  else
    index <= 0;
  end if;
end if;
```

---

**Ok, other problems in the code:**

```
if rst = '1' then 
  index <= 0; 
end if;
if stp = '1' then 
  index <= index; 
end if;

if ck100hz = '1' then
  -- ...
end if;
```

Reset should always have highest priority. In your case, e.g. `stp` has higher priority. In a good case you're only wasting FPGA resources, in a bad case synthesis can not translate your code to primitives in the FPGA. E.g. flip-flops with matching reset behavior.

Correct implementation:

```
if rst = '1' then 
  index <= 0; 
elsif stp = '1' then 
  index <= index; 
elsif ck100hz = '1' then
  -- ...
end if;
```

I think for now, you have enough input to fix your code.

Comment: @Paebbles Thanks for the explicitly explaining `elsif` and `rst`、`stp` problems,I now get these parts.But I still don't understand the part about No Driver for `S` and `scan`,if I want drive these two,how do I do that?
And about the low-active part,`Cathode_n <= not C` where does this fit into the code?
Thank again for asking more specific examples.

Comment: @doverdxJYGtw I did some extensions.

Comment: @Paebbles 
Thanks,I'll keep trying.Your explaining is getting me somewhere thanks agian.